# How to implement a key, value pair object within an interface in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, object

It seems quite a simple problem. I am basically trying to create a key value pair object within an interface I have created.

However I have no idea of how to implement this. I consistently get the error
Generic type 'Map' requires 2 type argument(s)

My interface object looks like this. I am trying to make the 'type' object to a key, value pair.

```
export interface CalendarEvent<MetaType = any> {
    id?: string | number;
    start: Date;
    end?: Date;
    title: string;
    color?: EventColor;
    actions?: EventAction[];
    allDay?: boolean;
    cssClass?: string;
    resizable?: {
        beforeStart?: boolean;
        afterEnd?: boolean;
    };
    draggable?: boolean;
    meta?: MetaType;
    amount: number;
    type: Map<key: string, value: string>
}
```

Comment: One way is `{ [key: string]: string }`, but if you want to use Map it's just `Map<string, string>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just supply the generic type - remove the parameter names, i.e:

`Map<string, string>`

Comment: would you know how to then access this object from my component? 
I tried this but I can't seem to access it this.events[i].type.values

Comment: Try `this.events[i].type.values()` - `values` is a method you need to call, not a property.
You can use the `get` method to access individual values using the stored `key`. 
i.e `this.events[i].type.get('stored_key')`

Here is a link to the documentation and the rest of the available methods and properties - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/prototype#Description